# view push notifications in GCM

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello Experts,
               I am developing an android application for an SAP mobile project. I am using PHP server-side scripting to send push notifications. The notifications are not seen on my GCM account under the project. Is it not possible to view them in GCM account or am I looking at some wrong place ? please help me with this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to view GCM stats from the API Console, you won't see anything, since they are not enabled. You must you the [developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).

> To view statistics and any error messages for your GCM applications:
>
> ```
> - Go to the Developer Console.
> - Login with your developer account.
>   You will see a page that has a list of all of your apps.
> - Click on the "statistics" link next to the app for which you want to view GCM
>   stats. Now you are on the statistics page.
> - Go to the drop-down menu and select the GCM metric you want to view.
> ```
>
> Note: **Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM.** You
>   must use the Developer Console.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#stats))

Comment: Thanks Eran. Google play developer consoles requires a premium account to login. I don't intend to buy one for this minor testing. I will complete the android part and try to view it in the device. Appreciate your help. :)